# html frames sizing parent according to child size

Tags: html, scroll, frames

i have 2 frames in my parent frame say 1.htm ie left frame and 2.htm ie right frame
now this 1.htm is quite a long frame and has a scrollbar
and 2.htm is a short one
i dont the scroll bar beside my frame 1 but want it to be for my entire parent window
ie i wont to scroll both my left and right frames together
how do i do that

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [Synchronized Frame Scrolling](http://www.javascriptsearch.com/tutorials/Beginner/tutorials/frame-scroll.html)